# Snowflake SQL - Format Phone Number to 9 digits

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with phone numbers in varchar, currently looks something like this.  Because there is no consistent format, I don't think substring works.

`(956) 444-3399`
`964-293-4321`
`(929)293-1234`
`(919)2991234`

How do I remove all brackets, spaces and dashes and have the query return just the digits, in Snowflake? The desired output:

`9564443399`
`9642934321`
`9292931234`
`9192991234`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()` function to achieve this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(yourcolumn, '[^0-9]','')
```

That will strip out any non-numeric character.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE($1, '[^0-9]','') AS T
FROM VALUES 
('+1 (922))1871234'),
('(922) 187-1234'),
('922-187-1234'),
('(922)187-1234'),
('(922)1871234'),
('(922)18712XX34'),
('@%(922)187@$,1234'),
('^@(922,1871234'),
('(^%^@!(929)299ASC1234AB')
;
```

[image: SNOWFLAKE EXAMPLE]

Comment: beautiful, that was easy!!! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use regexp_replace to remove all of the special characters

something like this

```
select regexp_replace('(956) 444-3399', '[\(\) -]', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `translate` . [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate.html)

```
 select translate('(956) 444-3399', '() -', '')
```